# I can't get extension points with Platform.getExtensionRegistry().getExtensionPoint

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Please someone help me,

I'm building a rcp app, It had worked well. But this morning, I ran it in Eclipse IDE, it was stated, but it silently terminated almost immediately. I fixed that problem by deleting the workspace folder of my rcp app and it works again.

But after fixing above problem, I can't get my extension point with `Platform.getExtensionRegistry().getExtensionPoint` because it always returns null. I'm sure that I've configured my extension point in the right way.

Additional information:
  - I use Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) on Window 7 32bit.
  - If I start my app as a hosted-plugin of Eclise IDE I can get my extension point, but stand-alone rcp app, it got the problem.

please help me call extension point back!
Thank you!

Comment: Its a good practice to share the answer with the community. If it was a trivial fix, please ignore. Also do close this question.

Comment: How did you solve the problem? You should answer your own question in this case.

Answer (score 0):

2 years passed, I'm sorry I didn't post the solution.

I think some resources were built into the workspace, when I was deleting the workspace of rcp app, I was also deleting all the resources so it could not get the extensions.

My solution was cleaning the project and it's dependencies. After cleaning, the project worked well.

Maybe someone got other solutions but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you give the fully qualified extension point name, I mean Plugin+extension point name.

I was trying to retrieve the extension point just by extension point name and this was the reason why null was being returned.

Hope this helps